# How to select columns from multiple table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I have two tables User and Order and association between those two table as follow.

in User model

```
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
```

in Order model

```
  belongs_to :user
```

I want to select all data from order table but instead of user_id I want to select name of that user from User table.

how can I do in rails?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this - User.includes(:orders).where(name: user_name).references(:orders). By this query you will get all orders based on user name.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do the following:

```
orders = Order.where(your_conditions).includes(:user)
```

And then:

```
orders.each do |order|
  order.user.name # implies that every order has a user
  # or
  order.user&.name # won't fail if order.user returns nil
end
```

This is called **eager loading**, you can find documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: I also try this 

        Order.find_by_sql('select users.name, orders.id from orders, users where orders.user_id=users.id') and 

    Order.joins(:user).select("oeders.*, user.name")
 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `Order.joins(:user).select('orders.*, users.name')` get the orders with all its columns and the name of the user in the same record, the table names should be passed as plural in the select instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make any special selection in your controller.

In your controller:

```
@orders =  Order.last(5) # gets 5 most recent orders
```

In your view:

```
@orders.each do |order|
  order.user.name # or order.user.first_name, e.t.c
end
```

Just access the user from the *order*.